# Re-obtaining a pre-created, forgotten secret using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I'm obtaining the ID of my registered application for the service principal.

```bash
az ad sp list --all --query "[?displayName=='Shazoo'].appId"
```

Then I'm obtaining the list of secrets registered for it.

```bash
az ad app credential list --id 2dda03c9-5d9b-4772-a666-c870a8c933c0
```

There's no `value`, however, only `hint`. I see how it follows what's available in the portal but I was hoping that I'd be able to retrieve it via the console somehow. (After all, the GUI won't let me set the expiration beyond 2 years but using the CLI, I can.)

Is there a way to re-obtain the secret? Or am I going to need to append a new one each time someone forgets what it was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secret value is only retrievable at the time of creation. You cannot get the secret value after that.

Only option available for you is to create a new secret and save its value some place safe (Key Vault, for example) so that it can be retrieved later.